# Why the non-null assertion operator (!) does not emit actual non-null & non-undefined checks into the resulting JS

Tags: typescript, null, undefined

It seems like it would be reasonable for the Typescript compiler to emit non-undefined & non-null checks into the resulting JS when using the non-null assertion operator. I.e.,:

```
function fun1(node: SomeType | undefined) {
    fun2(node!);
}
```

should get converted to:

```
function fun1(node) {
    if (node === undefined || node === null) {
        throw new Error('The non-null assertion failed!');
    }
    fun2(node);
}
```

However, as fas as the docs say, it will just get transpiled just to:

```
function fun1(node) {
    fun2(node);
}
```

Why is that so? What's the reason behind not adding the checks into the output JS code?

Comment: [TypeScript Design Goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals)

Comment: @Andreas what do you mean specifically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point of the non-null assertion operator is to tell the TypeScript compiler that you already know the variable is not null. Consider the following scenario:

```
function fun1(node: SomeType | undefined) {
    throwIfUndefined(node);
    node!.fun2();
}
```

You call a function which you know will throw an exception if `node` is undefined. Thus, there is really no need to check if node is undefined before the call to `fun2`. However, the TypeScript compiler can't infer that, so without the exclamation it will refuse to compile your code because it thinks you didn't handle the null case. But if you as the programmer know that condition would never happen, why insert a redundant check that will cost CPU cycles in the end product? The non-null assertion operator is really just a way to tell the compiler, "yes, I know you can't tell that this variable won't be null, but I'm doing so get out of my way."

Besides, what would be the point of throwing an error right before code that would throw an error anyway? A message like 'The non-null assertion failed!' is no more helpful than the standard null reference message.

Comment: This was just an example, but for this particular case, we can do better than using the exclamation mark, as it is not a practice to encourage, because it cancels the benefits of using TypeScript.

function ensureNotNullNorUndefined<T>(object?: T | null): T {
  if (object === null || object === undefined) {
    throw new Error("Assertion failed: object is null or undefined.");
  } else {
    return object;
  }
}

function fun1(node: SomeType | undefined) {
  ensureNotNullNorUndefined(node).fun2();
}

interface SomeType {
  fun2: () => void;
}

Comment: All you've done there is to explicitly code up a check that the runtime is going to do for you anyway. The error message that you provide does not provide any additional insight over the error message the runtime would give you.

Comment: At least it will fail at the exact place where we made that falsy assumption, and not far far away from it, which may happen when we pass the variable in a function that doesn't expect it to be `null` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

That is type assertion, that means you tell the compiler that that variable is not null, not to ask the compiler to check that variable. Basically, your idea is possible, but throwing an error is not the purpose of type assertion. And that's the different between TypeScript and Javascript (type check and value check)

Comment: Yes, but basically, it seems to be reasonable to check and throw an error whenever a variable that is supposed to be non-nullable/undefinedable is actually null/undefined

Comment: But how if you don't want to throw an error? there'll be no way to get through this case then

Comment: We could use general type assertion like `let smth: SomeType | undefined; (smth as SomeType).property`.
I know, this syntax is quite verbose, but how often would anyone want to not throw an error?

Comment: I don't think there'll be too many cases like that. But if you assert it, then you should beware of that. Otherwise, the bundle will grow huge and we couldn't control it. Maybe someone can create a dev dependency to do that. But for TypeScript itself, that assertion maybe equal to other type assertion. and the check will be damm complicated for the other types. Do you think so?